# Would anybody explain this code to me especially the for loops?

Tags: c, loops

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
main()
{
    int i,flag = 1,n,newn;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter number...");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(newn = 2;newn <= n;newn++)
    {
        flag=1;
        for(i=2;i<=newn/2 ;i++) //what would be the initial value of variable "newn" will be.

        {
            if(newn % i == 0)
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 1)
            printf("%d ",newn);
    }
    getch();
}
```

What would be the initial value of inner for loop when it would iterate for the first time? And why the outer `for` loop is needed in this program?

Comment: and also help me with flag=1 , i mean what is the need of flag = 1

Comment: This appears to be a crude way of printing all the prime numbers less than or equal to the number entered.  Is that enough help?

Comment: Is one of your several questions about the initial value of `for(i=2;i<=newn/2 ;i++)` ? What is unclear about that?

Comment: This kind of code can be understood by executing it yourself with penn and paper. Even if you actually do not know what the code is achieving in the end - though I believe that you did know or could find out by trying.

Comment: Please explain about the context of this code. If for example you are looking at the solution of a class mate for a homework assignment and try to understand it well enough too pass yourself, then it the help we could give you would be different from the help we could give you in case you needed a solution and downloaded this code from somewhere.

Comment: yes i did try on paper and now i have understood most of the code but now i am not getting the use of flag variable can you please explain me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code prints all Prime numbers between 2 and the number you entered. I rewrite the code to make it more clear what it does

```
int main()
{
    int flag=1, max_number = 100;
    // Flag determines if we have a prime number of not
    // flag = 1, prime number found
    // flag = 0, no prime number found
    printf("Please Enter a number bigger then 2 and press enter : \n");
    scanf("%d",&max_number);

    printf("List of prime numbers from 2 to %d : \n", max_number);

    // Counts from 2 till the halb of the number you entered, since 0 and 1 
    // are not interesting for us
    for(int current_number = 2; current_number <= max_number; current_number++)
    {

        flag=1;
        // Counts from 2 till the half of the current_number and check if its a prime 
        // number 

        for(int i = 2; i <= current_number/2 ; i++)
        {
            //printf("Outer loop : %d Inner Loop %d\n", current_number, i);

            // Checks if we have a prime number
            if(current_number % i ==0)
            {
              // No we have not a prime number, quit this one and check next number
              flag=0;
              break;
            }
        }

        // Prime number found
        if(flag==1)
            printf("Prime number found: %d \n", current_number);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The Output for max_number = 15 would be :

```
 Prime number found: 11                                                                                                                                                             
    Outer loop : 12 Inner Loop 2                                                                                                                                                       
    Outer loop : 13 Inner Loop 2                                                                                                                                                       
    Outer loop : 13 Inner Loop 3                                                                                                                                                       
    Outer loop : 13 Inner Loop 4                                                                                                                                                       
    Outer loop : 13 Inner Loop 5                                                                                                                                                       
    Outer loop : 13 Inner Loop 6                                                                                                                                                       
    Prime number found: 13                                                                                                                                                             
    Outer loop : 14 Inner Loop 2                                                                                                                                                       
    Outer loop : 15 Inner Loop 2                                                                                                                                                       
    Outer loop : 15 Inner Loop 3
```

Comment: hi i am beginner in programming and i want to start by learning C language. can you tell me how i can clear me programming logic and if you know any other website where i can learn programming please let me know.

Comment: Google c tutorials